# How split one json data into 2 file in cloud function using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The need is to create 2 files in cloud storage bucket using the json data available in pubsub.

```
{"ltime":"2022-04-12T11:33:00.970Z","cnt":199,"fname":"MYFILENAME","data":[{"NAME":"N1","ID":11.4,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"},{"NAME":"M1","ID":25.0,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"}]
```

Expected is:

1. Create MYFILENAME.json and then write data values - [{"NAME":"N1","ID":11.4,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"},{"NAME":"M1","ID":25.0,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"}]
2. Create MYFILENAME.csv file and then write ltime:2022-04-12T11:33:00.970Z, cnt:199
   (comma separated file and without double quotes)

As per my need I have written Python code to use cloud functions, but it may serves one way not both.

```
def pubsub_to_gcs(event, context):
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(pubsub_message)
    jsonfile = data['filename'] + '.json'
    try:
        to_gcs(os.environ['project'], os.environ['bucket'], jsonfile, pubsub_message)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(e))

def to_gcs(project_id, bucket, jsonfile, document):
     storage_client = storage.Client(gcs_project_id)
     bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(gcs_bucket_name)
     blob = bucket.blob(jsonfile)
     blob.upload_from_string(data=document, content_type='application/json')
```

Ultimately my bucket should look like this with above data added:

```
my-bucket
   MYFILENAME.json
   MYFILENAME.csv
```

Please let me know how to handle both ?

Comment: If I clearly understood what you are expecting to develop, all you have to do is add a code to generate a csv similar to the one you used for json. Just your content_type will be text/csv. Does this answer?

Comment: I have added some more information for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You are already half way, just generate a csv data programatically below the json file handling code and then use the to_gcs code to upload the data to gcs. make sure to change the content_type to "text/csv".

Comment: how to handle ltime and cnt in csv file - I need to write the data like this ltime:2022-04-12T11:33:00.970Z, cnt:199

Comment: You can get it from the JSON object using `[]` or `get()` like `data.get("ltime")` !?

Comment: you can format string like "{}:{}".format("ltime",<time from pubsub>). That way you will have quotes on the outer end only which is necessary. Does this answer?